# How to enable systray Quickstarter in libreoffice 6

Tags: 18.04, libreoffice

In LibreOffice 6, the `tools>options>LibreOffice>Memory` was removed.

Is there any way to use the systray Quickstarter in this version of LibreOffice? That option used to make LibreOffice much faster.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with the official PPA of LibreOffice.

Update: The [bug report](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=123959) has been reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is a regression in version 6.1 and this feature has been completely removed. However, it can be enabled in the version 6.0.7.3 in the bionic main repository.
Install the package `libreoffice-systray` and enable systray Quickstarter in `Tools>Options>LibreOffice>General`.

Then you can add `libreoffice --quickstarter` to startup applications.

Comment: Note: Libreoffice 6.3 is now much faster, even without the quickstarter.

Answer (score 2):

The Quickstarter [is deprecated](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/ReleaseNotes/5.4#General_2), as of libreoffice 5.4.  From what I can gather, it was finally removed in version 6.1.  I was sad to see it go as well.  Like you say, it sped things up quite a bit, especially on slower hardware.  I guess I should really be upgrading some of my 1990's hardware... :)

In all seriousness, I think the answer is basically *no,* you can't use the quickstarter, unless you want to design some kind of custom script that would run the soffice app in the background somehow without opening a window, while still allowing libreoffice windows to open...  Alternatively, you can simply put `libreoffice` in your startup applications and simply leave the basic window open on different workspace.  Yeah.  Annoying, but I'm afraid that's the best you'll get.

Comment: It appears to be just Linux.  At any rate, I've seen no evidence to the contrary, and the release notes say "Linux Quickstarter is removed."

Comment: I have created a bug report. https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=123959