# How to use the package libreoffice-systray?

Tags: 18.04, libreoffice

In LibreOffice 6, the systray Quickstarter was removed but there is a package called `libreoffice-systray` in the repositories.

Can this package be used to run libreoffice in the system tray?
I installed this package but cannot figure out how to use it.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with the official `LibreOffice Fresh` PPA.

Previously I asked the question [How to enable systray quickstarter in libreoffice](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1123571/how-to-enable-systray-quickstarter-in-libreoffice-6) and there was no positive answer. Later I saw that there is a package called `libreoffiec-systray`, so I am asking how to use it.
So this question is not a duplicate of that, although their answer may be similar once we find how to use this package.

Comment: Just for completeness, please [edit the question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1123660/edit) the version of LibO. When 6.2 reaches the fresh ppa things may be different. Currently, the ppa seems to still be on 6.1.5.2.

Comment: Does `libreoffice --quickstart` work from the command line?

Comment: I think this is not a duplicate. I have explained why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the option has been completely removed from version 6.1 onwards. However, in version 6.0.7.3 (which is available in the bionic main repositories) it can be enabled.

The `libreoffice-systray` package creates an enable systray Quickstarter checkmark in `tools > options > LibreOffice > General`

You can enable the checkbox, and add `libreoffice --quickstarter` to the startup applications.

Answer (score 0):

The LibreOffice quickstart was deprecated in 5.4, and now it's been eliminated
The `libreoffice-systray` package simply installs a .desktop file with the launch command `libreoffice --quickstart --nologo --nodefault` which as no effect since version 6.1
See official website for more information:
https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/164223/no-quickstarter-after-last-update/